# Polarion API doesn't let me connect

Tags: python, polarion

I am writing a script in Python to import testcases as workitems in Polarion. I am now at the point where I write the module to connect to Polarion. I 100% enter the correct URL and username and password.

The script is:

```
from polarion import polarion
import getpass

user = input("Username: ")
password = getpass.getpass(prompt="Password:")
server = ('http://example.com/polarion')

pol = polarion.Polarion(server, user, password, verify_certificate = ('path_to_my_certificate.crt'))

project = pol.getProject('PSA_Sandbox')
workitem = project.createWorkitem('probe_work_item')
workitem.setDescription('Das ist ein Testupload')
```

In the console I get the following error:

> Fault: Authentication failed.; nested exception is:
> com.polarion.platform.security.AuthenticationFailedException: Sorry, but the Username or Password is invalid.
>
> Exception: Could not log in to Polarion for user PS8

I don't know what is wrong there and would appreciate some help!

Comment: Have you tried to connect to the end point via something like cURL in a command line session? If you get the same result there, it's not your code

Comment: Which Python module / version of "polarion" are you using?

Comment: Current Company Polarion Version: Polarion® ALM™ 21 R2. And i am writing my script with Anaconda Spyder V5.4.3 and Python 3.11.3

Comment: What happens if you hardcode both Username and PW?

Comment: The same result, thats why i am 100% i am entering the correct password and user.

Comment: any special chars (international characters) in pw?